# Como recuperar old values de inputs select?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Segue o código da blade:

```
<select name="tipo_id" class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <option value=""></option>
    @foreach ($tipos as $tipo )
       <option name="tipo_id" value="{{$tipo->id}}">
           {{$tipo->description}}
       </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para recuperar o valor escolhido após uma requisição chame a função `old('tipo_id')` e vendo o seu código foi feito o `<select></select>` na mão utilize um `if` dentro do `option` para setar o que foi escolhido, exemplo:

```
<select name="tipo_id" class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <option value=""></option>
    @foreach ($tipos as $tipo )
       <option name="tipo_id" value="{{$tipo->id}}" @if(old('tipo_id')==$tipo->id) {{'selected'}} @endif>
           {{$tipo->description}}
       </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```